# Debo crear un modelo en Laravel para una tabla pivot de 3 tablas?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mvc

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que se realizan simulaciones de exámenes. Los exámenes se generan para cada usuario con preguntas aleatorias. Existen preguntas y cada una tiene sus respuestas, una de ellas es la correcta. A su vez el usuario realiza el examen, y responde preguntas, seleccionando una de las respuestas. Lo mismo que un examen de opción múltiple.

Me conviene crear un modelo intermedio que sea algo así como ExamenRespuesta (AnswerTest)? o cómo puedo lograr relacionar Test con Answer y Question?
Mi idea es poder recrear las preguntas del examen con la respuesta que seleccionó el usuario, para poder visualizarlo.

[image: Modelo base de datos]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tu pregunta suena a basada en opiones (es mas, estas pidiendo opiniones). podes hacer una pregunta clara? porque este modelo que estas mostrando no funcionaria?

Comment: La pregunta es clara. Cómo relaciono Test con Answer y Question? Debo crear un modelo para la tabla answer_test?

Comment: en ese modelo la tabla test ya esta relacionada con la tabla answer. leiste los links que te pase sobre como funciona el sitio?

Comment: A nivel de base de datos están relacionadas, a nivel de modelos de Laravel no.

Comment: ok Jeremias, entonces deberias aclarar eso en la pregunta, yo solo vi que preguntabas sobre un modelo de base de datos, y mostrabas un modelo de base de datos. fijate que la pregunta es muy diferente entonces, y no tiene nada que ver con la base de datos y va a llevar a confusion sobre las respuestas que vas a recibir. Usa el boton [edit] y explica bien donde esta el problema.. Bienvenido!